# Remove elements in a string after an "exact match" in stringr

Tags: dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I have a character like this:

```
a <- "PP Express Transaction_ID: 1234"
```

I would like to remove everything after "PP Express " like:

```
a_final <- "PP Express"
```

I tried with:

```
a <- "PP Express Transaction_ID: 1234"
gsub("PP Express*", "", a)
```

but I get the exact contrary...

moreover: id I wanted to apply this on a dataframe column, I would like to perform the operation only for the rows containing this exact substring!

I tried with str_extract() but I get null values if the row doesn't contain the substring at all.

Comment: `str_extract(a, "PP Express")`. What's your expected output when there is no match?

Comment: so, imagining to apply this to a column dataframe, when there is the match str_extract() behaves correctly; when there is no match I get NA. I would like to keep the column value for the non matching. Maybe something with a case_when?

Comment: `grepl("PP Express", col2)` works fine in a mutate call. Use and ifelse statement to do whatever you want with column.